# Sonarqube & Dotcover - Coverage Metric is N/A or '-'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0, dotcover

I am running dotcover to generate a coverage report and then running that through sonarqube 5.0.1 (via Jenkins plugin). I used to have coverage metrics from previous runs, however, not sure what changed in build job / source code that now code coverage shows "-", even though all tests are successful (except 1 skipped). Not sure why this happens. Looking at the dotcover report generated - I can see the coverage, just not in sonar.

Pic:

[image]
[image]

Can anyone provide simple troubleshoot steps for this scenario?
Jenkins build log does not show any relevant error or exception.

Any insight on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Make sure your test dlls didn't count in the calculation...

Comment: How are you analyzing your C# project in SonarQube? Have you migrated to the new MSBuild SonarQube Runner? If so, you can refer to the official dotCover documentation: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Code+Coverage+Results+Import

Comment: In any case, please provide the logs (either from the `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end` phase, or from the `sonar-runner`) - and make sure absolute paths referenced in your dotCover HTML report matches exactly the ones of the file you are trying to analyzing in SonarQube

Comment: @freebourn of course... first, for a fully disclosure I've never used `sonarqube` before however, usually a problems as you described occurs because in the first execution the configuration contained the test dlls in the calculation and in the second execution the test dlls were missing....